# Dealing with Vary Input Size in Spatial Pyramid Pooling Network (SPP)

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

In [Spatial Pyramid Pooling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4729), I still did not get why we need Spatial Pyramid Pooling after the input layer. The motivation behind SPP according to the authors is to deal with input features of different sizes and generate a fixed representation output for further layers. But does not the previous layer that produces input features for SPP is of fixed size? So why do we need to design SPP to deal with input features of different sizes, please? If SPP is used at the beginning of the network as the input layer, that would make sense to use SPP to deal with various input sizes, but why do we need to use it in the neck, which is basically in the middle of the network?